# What exactly does a synchronized method do?

Tags: java, methods, synchronized, runnable

I'm creating a game using Swing. I made `start()` and `stop()` synchronized because I was told it was better. What does synchronized do and what is the advantage in using it?

My code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SpritePractice extends Canvas implements Runnable{

private JFrame frame;
private final static int WIDTH = 200, HEIGHT = 200;
private final static int SCALE = 2;
private final static Dimension dimens= new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics g;
private long nanoSecond = 1000000000;
private double tick = nanoSecond/60;
private boolean running = false;
private int pixelsFromImage[];
private int pixel[][];
private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("[" + "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        +"]");
private static DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("[" + "HH:mm:ss" + "]");

public SpritePractice()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Bomberman");
    frame.setSize(dimens);
    frame.setMinimumSize(dimens);
    frame.setMaximumSize(dimens);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    init();
}
public void init()
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("START: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    start();
}

public void run() 
{
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    long lastTick = System.nanoTime();
    long lastSecond = System.nanoTime();
    int frames = 0;

    while(running)
    {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(now-lastTick >= tick)
        {
            lastTick = now;
            tick();
            render();
            frames++;
        }   
        if(now-lastSecond >= nanoSecond)
        {
            lastSecond = now;
            System.out.println(dateFormat2.format(cal.getTime()) + "FPS: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
}
public void tick()
{
    //updates values
}
public void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs==null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH*2, HEIGHT*2);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
    //renders graphics
}
public synchronized void start()
{
    running = true;
    run();
}
public synchronized void stop()
{
    running = false;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new SpritePractice();
}
```

}

Comment: [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#syncmethod) may help

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: invoking the `run()` method inside the start method doesn't make sense(at least for me), maybe it's `new Thread(this).start()` ?!

Comment: concurrency is a complex topic. You should definitely understand what you're doing before using multiple threads. This program is not thread-safe. Fortunately, it doesn't start any thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread that enters a synchronized method obtains a lock on the entire object who owns the method.

In your particular case, you can be sure that there won't be two concurrent threads that execute `start()` and `stop()` simultaneously.

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) more about synchronized methods.

e.g. if one thread enters the `start()` method, it will complete its execution before another thread could enter the `stop()` method. Without synchronizing the 2 methods, the following succession is possible:

-- thread 1 enters `start()`
-- thread 1 sets boolean field to `true`
-- thread 2 enters `stop()`
-- thread 2 sets `boolean` field to `false`
-- thread 1 executes `run()` method

which you definitely don't want.

Comment: Okay. So if a thread attempts to execute a synchronized method while some other synchronized method has not finished executing, synchronizing both methods ensures that the first method executes and finishes completely , before allowing the thread that called the second method to execute?

Comment: Exactly. As long as they try to call methods of the same object.

Comment: Thank you very much, and to everyone else for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Every object instance in Java has an implicit mutex lock on it.  Synchronized on a method is equivalent to the following code:

```
synchronized void foo() {
  // Some code here
}
void foo() {
  synchronized(this) {
    // Same code here
  }
}
```

The net effect is that when two threads try to simultaneously execute that block of code, one waits at the 'synchronized' statement until the other emerges from the block.  This ensures that the "code here" portion is only being run on one thread at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else has explained this in plain English, I will:

Marking a method as "synchronized" means that you don't want multiple threads to access the method at the same time. This is useful if you don't want your code to allow so-called "race condition" meaning - again in plain English - "whichever thread reaches here first, wins".

Here's an example:
Imagine a simple bank application that can redraw and deposit money. If you have three threads running - 3 ATM's placed around in a small town - you would like all three threads (ATM's) to be able to deposit money and redraw money to/from the same account at the same time, if needed.

Without synchronization a race condition happens. Let's see:
On the bank account is $100. Person A would like to deposit $20. Person B would like to deposit $50. Person C would like to redraw $130. This is possible if Person A deposits before Person B deposits which happens before Person C redraws. But here's the catch!

Before Person A deposits, $100 is on the account. The deposit method could look like this:

```
// Naive deposit
public void deposit(double amount) {
    double currentAmount = getCurrentAmount(); // Critical
    setCurrentAmount(currentAmount + amount);
}
```

When Person A deposits, the ATM needs to retrieve the current amount, add up the amount the person wants to deposit and set the current balance to that amount. At the critical point (marked `// Critial`) however, person B could have deposited, too. Here's a breakdown of what could go wrong, if ATM A (Person A's ATM) and ATM B (Person B's ATM) deposits at the exact same time:

- ATM A retrieves the current amount. $100 is returned.
- ATM B retrieves the current amount. $100 is returned.
- ATM B updates the current amount to $100 + $50 = $150.
- ATM B stores $150 as the total amount on the account.
- ATM A, thinking there is only $100 on the account, updates the total balance to $120.

Someone just lost $30 because ATM B finished before ATM A did, at the critical point! This is the "race condition" - it's all a matter of who comes first.

Now to the `synchronized` keyword! This keyword puts a virtual lock on the method, meaning that only the thread (ATM) that was given the "key" for this "lock", can execute the code. All other threads have to wait for the thread with this magical "key" to finish. In the bank example above, this means that ATM A would finish off depositing $20 into the account, before ATM B could retrieve the current amount and deposit another $50.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized allows the correct thread handling , this way Java will create a queue and handling the different threads that your might span in your app without you having to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `stop()` method before `start()` invoking finished.and vise versa. `synchronized`  keyword quadrates that there is not two thread in `start()` and `stop()` method at the same time of invocation.

In other words, when you push the start() button, you are not allowed to push stop() button until starting completed.